# After reopening colab, sometimes bokeh plots don't load randomly

Tags: google-colaboratory, bokeh

I have a Google colab that includes bokeh plots, with some widgets like sliders. These plots show nicely after I run the code cells. When I close and reopen the notebook, sometimes it works (figures load after reopening without running the code), however sometimes randomly (say 10% of time), they fail to load (nothing is displayed in the cell output), and in Google Chrome console I can see error like this:

`Uncaught Error: Model 'Slider' does not exist. This could be due to a widget or a custom model not being registered before first usage.`

So it seems like sometimes a needed JavaScript component isn't loaded properly. How to ensure it is and get rid of this problem?

Comment: Are you calling `output_notebook` at/near the top of the notebook, in its own cell? Are you specifying inline or CDN resources?

Comment: First I was calling `output_notebook` in the separate (top) cell, then I tried also calling it in every cell where I also have some plots. Both have the problem that I've described above. As for resources, I do not specify them, so it defaults to CDN.

Comment: You might try inline resources instead. Unfortunately, issues on collab have historically been difficult to diagnose (since Google's dev process for collab is completely opaque) and also very slow to resolve (trying to prod google to look at things to look into things on their end has taken *years* in the past). I am afraid I don't have a magic bullet to offer.

Comment: If you can reproduce the same issue outside collab, with standard notebooks, please open an issue with all relevant details. That would be something we can actually investigate.

Comment: I checked and inlining resources does indeed help! With the following code it just works:

`from bokeh.io import output_notebook`
`from bokeh.resources import Resources`
`output_notebook(resources=Resources('inline'))`